# How to add pagination to a single post

Tags: pagination

I have a template for a custom post-type `single-continent.php` which calls a secondary WP_Query loop to load a list of posts.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'meta_query'  => array($meta_queries),
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'paged'       => $paged,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'post'
));
```

The function is setup to use `get_query_var()` to check for page/paged but I cannot seem to make the URL `/page/2` work. Instead I get a 301 redirect back to the continent. I can use `/2` which is picked up by `get_query_var('page')` but not sure if this is the correct solution (and I need to be able to use this with `the_posts_pagination`.

Comment: refer to this previous posted  [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176723/creating-a-simple-pagination-for-custom-post-type-templates)

Comment: That question isn't quite what I need - they are looping through `news` posts on a page, but I have a custom post type here. I don't want to look through `continents` but rather loop through `posts` from my continent page itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgive me for answering my own question, but this post gave me the answer I needed: [WP_Query Pagination on single-custom.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143812/wp-query-pagination-on-single-custom-php)

I had to take a copy of the original wp_query

```
$original_query = $wp_query;
```

then assign my custom loop to the global `$wp_query`, and finally reset everything with

```
wp_reset_postdata();
$wp_query = $original_query;
```

In essence, this is what was missing:

```
function mytheme_template_redirect() {
    if(is_singular('continent')) {
        global $wp_query;
        $page = (int)$wp_query->get('page');
        if($page > 1) {
            $query->set('page', 1);
            $query->set('paged', $page);
        }
        remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
    }
}
```

Called with:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'mytheme_template_redirect', 0);
```

Everything works fine now as I'm no longer getting a 301 redirect when appending `/page/2` to the (single) custom post URL